# How to fix 'Android App freezing at Splash Screen' activity?

Tags: android

My app is freezing at splash screen activity after pull from git. Which led me some conflicts and I removed the conflicts. After that my app is freezing at splash screen. Even the app is not crashing, also showing no errors at logcat. How to solve it? I am sharing the codes of my Splash Screen class below,

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    /* New Handler to start the Main Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
  }
}
```

I am providing my `MainActivity` class codes below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button bt_SignIn, bt_SignUp;
SharedPref sharedPref;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final InternetConnectionChecker internetConnectionChecker = new InternetConnectionChecker(getApplicationContext());

    bt_SignUp = findViewById(R.id.bt_signUp);
    bt_SignIn = findViewById(R.id.bt_signIn);

    sharedPref = new SharedPref(getApplicationContext());

    if (sharedPref.getLogInData()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
      }
    }

    bt_SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (internetConnectionChecker.isConnected()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtpSenderActivity.class));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (internetConnectionChecker.isConnected()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I am attaching my logcat status, this is running. I just captured a page of log.

[image]

Comment: Please post log, it will be easy to identify error.

Comment: probably the problem is in `MainActivity`. I don;t see any problems in this code.

Comment: check AndroidManifest did you have activity mention over there

Comment: Can you please add the main activity code snippet?

Comment: does it work if you comment `getWindow().setFlags()`

Comment: @SurajGhadge I have posted a screenshot of logcat.

Comment: @SurajGhadge Yes I have activity mention in manifest file.

Comment: @ShreyGarg it remains same after commenting `getWindow().setFlags()` lines

Comment: @Sunny I have added `MainActivity.class` codes

Comment: @Md.RejaulKarim In main activity, everything looks good. You need to add the debugger points and check the issue your self. in Home activity as well

Comment: @Sunny I have solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

 private int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Window window = getWindow();
 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);







new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
       }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
 }
}
```

aslo check the manifest is your MainActivity is defined or not

still if is not working remove the flag set for window, instead add

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

in manifest under splash activity for full sceen